# Solr - How do I construct a query that requires a NULL or EMPTY Location field

Tags: solr

I have to get all items where the field "allowedChannels_string_mv"
is empty or null. I tried to add "(allowedChannels_string_mv:'')" as a filter raw query but it doesn't works

What is the query syntax to perform the NULL or EMPTY check on a Location field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax in your `q` parameter:

```
NOT allowedChannels_string_mv:*
```

which translates to `allowedChannels_string_mv` does not have any value.